# How can I use readline() to begin from the second line?

Tags: python

I'm writing a short program in Python that will read a FASTA file which is usually in this format:

```
>gi|253795547|ref|NC_012960.1| Candidatus Hodgkinia cicadicola Dsem chromosome, 52 lines
GACGGCTTGTTTGCGTGCGACGAGTTTAGGATTGCTCTTTTGCTAAGCTTGGGGGTTGCGCCCAAAGTGA
TTAGATTTTCCGACAGCGTACGGCGCGCGCTGCTGAACGTGGCCACTGAGCTTACACCTCATTTCAGCGC
TCGCTTGCTGGCGAAGCTGGCAGCAGCTTGTTAATGCTAGTGTTGGGCTCGCCGAAAGCTGGCAGGTCGA
```

I've created another program that reads the first line(aka header) of this FASTA file and now I want this second program to start reading and printing beginning from the sequence.

How would I do that?

so far i have this:

```
FASTA = open("test.txt", "r")

def readSeq(FASTA):
    """returns the DNA sequence of a FASTA file"""
    for line in FASTA:
        line = line.strip()
        print line          


readSeq(FASTA)
```

Thanks guys

-Noob

Comment: I was thinking...maybe use a while loop to see whether or not the first letter of the second line is  a subset of the set('ACGT').

Answer (score 5):

```
def readSeq(FASTA):
    """returns the DNA sequence of a FASTA file"""
    _unused = FASTA.next() # skip heading record
    for line in FASTA:
        line = line.strip()
        print line
```

Read [the docs on file.next()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) to see why you should be wary of mixing `file.readline()` with `for line in file:`

Comment: As far as I understood this point, as far as I verified it, and as far as I know, the use of ``readline()`` before any execution of a ``for line in one_file:`` loop or ``next()`` function is safe. That's when such an execution of a loop or ``next()`` is processed before a ``readline()`` that things go bad. But even in this case, it is possible to take control again and to perform treatments without scramble by using ``tell()`` and ``seek()`` : _"However, using seek() to reposition the file to an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer."_ in the doc of **next()**

Comment: @eyquem: Rather than having to consult a grimoire to determine when it is safe to mix in ancient potions like `readline()`, I'd prefer to avoid using it. Your arcane lore is useful only for debugging code, not for writing code or telling newbies what code to write. In any case, 3 * "As far as I" and you're out :-)

Comment: (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) isn't a grimoire. I detest esoteric languages such as perl or even C++, and there are 164 pages of arcane recipes written by seasoned pythonistas on (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/). I don't push newbies to use tricky recipes, I only inform of the real things in order to avoid that a urban legend about the mix of readline() and next() be spread. As soon as I've understood a point enough to be rather confident, I don't have anymore reticence to use it. Or I would have never begun to use comprehension lists

Comment: There is no need to create an identifier **_unusued** , ``FASTA.next()`` alone works. By the way , I find this is the best solution because **FASTA.readline()** does the reading of the first line and the file's pointer stops at the end of this first line. Hence when the iteration must be done, the program must triggers a reading again (and this time a read-ahead buffer is fulfilled). On the contrary, if **FASTA.next()** is executed , the read-ahead buffer is fulfilled at once. It spares an action and a processing of the arm in the hard drive. As far as I understand.

Answer (score 4):

you should show your script. To read from second line, something like this

```
f=open("file")
f.readline()
for line in f:
    print line
f.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention im defining a function

Comment: That works with no problem, but ``f.next()`` is better. See my comment at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in checking [**`BioPythons`**](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) handling of Fasta files ([**`source`**](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqIO/FastaIO.py#L35)).

```
def FastaIterator(handle, alphabet = single_letter_alphabet, title2ids = None):
    """Generator function to iterate over Fasta records (as SeqRecord objects).

handle - input file
alphabet - optional alphabet
title2ids - A function that, when given the title of the FASTA
file (without the beginning >), will return the id, name and
description (in that order) for the record as a tuple of strings.

If this is not given, then the entire title line will be used
as the description, and the first word as the id and name.

Note that use of title2ids matches that of Bio.Fasta.SequenceParser
but the defaults are slightly different.
"""
    #Skip any text before the first record (e.g. blank lines, comments)
    while True:
        line = handle.readline()
        if line == "" : return #Premature end of file, or just empty?
        if line[0] == ">":
            break

    while True:
        if line[0]!=">":
            raise ValueError("Records in Fasta files should start with '>' character")
        if title2ids:
            id, name, descr = title2ids(line[1:].rstrip())
        else:
            descr = line[1:].rstrip()
            id = descr.split()[0]
            name = id

        lines = []
        line = handle.readline()
        while True:
            if not line : break
            if line[0] == ">": break
            #Remove trailing whitespace, and any internal spaces
            #(and any embedded \r which are possible in mangled files
            #when not opened in universal read lines mode)
            lines.append(line.rstrip().replace(" ","").replace("\r",""))
            line = handle.readline()

        #Return the record and then continue...
        yield SeqRecord(Seq("".join(lines), alphabet),
                         id = id, name = name, description = descr)

        if not line : return #StopIteration
    assert False, "Should not reach this line"
```

Answer (score 1):

good to see another bioinformatician :)

just include an if clause within your for loop above the line.strip() call

```
def readSeq(FASTA):
    for line in FASTA:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            continue
        line = line.strip()
        print(line)
```

Comment: That's a bad solution because you oblige the program to do the test for ALL the lines, even for the ones for which it's no more necessary

Comment: @eyquem Doesn't matter much, since the complexity is linear. Plus i parse like hundreds of these files (and clustal files) daily, and most of them are 100+MB having multiple sequences in each (separated by that header ('>...')), and never had any problem. The if clause allows to separate all those sequences in each of the files, so this helps keep the method flexible enough.

Comment: _"complexity is linear"_ : err, what does it mean ? - Separating sequences is another aim than the one asked by Francis - For this separating task, I think that reading the entire file at once and using a regex to detect each sequence should be better, IMO. It would be more efficient than this use of **startswith()**

Comment: @eyquem Since most of out data (by our, i mean in bioinformatics, example is the OP's file) is parsing terabytes of text, we need to keep our algorithms less complex (complexity is measured in steps (constants) and nested loops (powers of N), these are useful in data structures and AI). Regex are good, but are more complex and consume a lot of memory on large data. Comparatively, a simple if clause only increase a linear step, meaning the complexity of this method goes from 4N to 6N, that is a linear increase of 2, which is negligible in most of our cases..

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic and simple way to do this would be slice notation.

```
>>> f = open('filename')
>>> lines = f.readlines()
>>> lines[1:]
['TTAGATTTTCCGACAGCGTACGGCGCGCGCTGCTGAACGTGGCCACTGAGCTTACACCTCATTTCAGCGC\n', 'TCGCTTGCTGGCGAAGCTGGCAGCAGCTTGTTAATGCTAGTG
TTGGGCTCGCCGAAAGCTGGCAGGTCGA']
```

That says "give me all elements of lines, from the second (index 1) to the end.

Other general uses of slice notation:

```
s[i:j]  slice of s from i to j
s[i:j:k]    slice of s from i to j with step k (k can be negative to go backward)
```

Either i or j can be omitted (to imply the beginning or the end), and j can be negative to indicate a number of elements from the end.

```
s[:-1]     All but the last element.
```

**Edit** in response to gnibbler's comment:

If the file is truly massive you can use [iterator slicing](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the same effect while making sure you don't get the whole thing in memory.

```
import itertools
f = open("filename")
#start at the second line, don't stop, stride by one
for line in itertools.islice(f, 1, None, 1): 
    print line
```

"islicing" doesn't have the nice syntax or extra features of regular slicing, but it's a nice approach to remember.

Comment: This is fine if you know the file is small. For larger files you don't want to read the whole thing into memory at once

Comment: @gnibbler: Quite right. I think the FASTA files tend to be small enough to do this, but added info about slicing with itertools as well.